# Change config file for Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

By default, Next.js uses next.config.js file for configuration.

How do you change that to something like my.next.config.js?

Answer (score 0):

After digging it is not currently possible (Feb 2023) to change location of next.config.js, but if you want to fully customize contents of the config you can build this yourself:

```js
// next.config.js
const actualConfig = process.env.NEXT_CONFIG_LOCATION

module.exports = require(actualConfig)
```

Then pass `NEXT_CONFIG_LOCATION=./my.next.config.js` to next.js commands (NEXT_CONFIG_LOCATION in this case is just an example).